# How can I retrieve emails of users within specific Fusion Teams project?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to retrieve the email list of Fusion Team users which have access to specific Fusion Team project. I guess it could be defined into two steps:

(1) Get users with access to specific Fusion Team Folder

(2) For each user get the corresponding email

Checking the Forge Data Management API v2 I see I can theoretically:

- Retrieve info about the specific Fusion Team Project (including user creator)
- Retrieve user info (including email address)
- Retrieve user permissions on a specific resource

I guess (2) is solved with the retrieval of user info, but do you know if Data Management API allows (1)? If so, how?

Thanks!!!

Comment: As I know, there is not yet API for Folder permission of Fusion Team. Only BIM360 exposes Folder Permission API. I am double checking with team.

Answer (score 0):

regarding with question #1, the API CheckPermission can be of use.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/CheckPermission/
It if a user has permission to perform specified actions on specified resources, including folder of Fusion Team.

It is different to the API of BIM360 Folder Permission, which returns the permission list & users. While CheckPermission is you input which permission you want to check, given a user and specific folder, the API will return if it is permitted or not.